# How to troubleshoot: protocol synchronization is lost

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, smach, tcpros, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suddenly I start seeing this error:

> [ERROR] [1520525542.826204079] [/rosout]: a message of over a
> gigabyte was predicted in tcpros. that
> seems highly unlikely, so I'll assume
> protocol synchronization is lost.

> [ERROR] [1520525542.826297310]
> [/rosout]: Exception thrown when
> deserializing message of length [0]
> from [/task_runner]: Buffer Overrun

> [ERROR] [1520525542.826355406]
> [/rosout]: Exception thrown when
> deserializing message of length
> [11596] from [/task_runner]: Buffer Overrun

Details:

- Seems to appear randomly
- The node `/task_runner` is running a large `smach` state machine, with a large number or topic subscriptions.
- There is only one PC involved.
- Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04

In the log for task_runner I found this error message at the same point in time:

```
[rospy.rosout][ERROR] 2018-03-09 08:28:55,914: Unable to report rosout: Set changed size during iteration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/rosout.py", line 91, in _rosout
    _rosout_pub.publish(l)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 882, in publish
    self.impl.publish(data)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 1066, in publish
    serialize_message(b, self.seq, message)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 152, in serialize_message
    msg.serialize(b)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph_msgs/msg/_Log.py", line 153, in serialize
    for val1 in self.topics:
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

So I conclude that the rosout logging breaks because I perform logging whiIe another thread is adding a topic to the same node. If so, how would I solve this in a generic way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284832/how-to-troubleshoot:-protocol-synchronization-is-lost/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is the problem:

The combination of logging to rosout and subscribing to topics is not threadsafe. I have created a new
[question](https://answers.ros.org/question/284911).

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0